# Order of rows returned by a query in different schema is different

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g, database-schema

I'm using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit.
I have created and inserted some date into a table " transfers " with fields

tsid(number,primary key),
 name(varchar 2(20)),
 desc(varchar 2(30)),
 qty (number),
 date (timestamp).

I have another schema `SHE` with same table and fields.
I copied the data to SHE schema using following query,

```
    INSERT INTO SHE.TRANSFERS ( SELECT * FROM HE.TRANSFERS );
```

When querying the table in schema HE and SHE, i get date is different order.

```
    select * from transfers;
```

What should i do for getting the rows at same order in both schema?

Please explain me about database row ordering.

Comment: In SQL, the results of a query have _no defined order_ UNLESS there is an ORDER BY clause.  The database is under no obligation to return rows in any specific order without ORDER BY.  In fact, the order could be different for different executions of the same query.

Comment: does my answer solved your issue? can you mark it as accepted? thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, It is very simple. We can solve this by using order by tsid.  But my question is why different schema return same data ordered differently. If i want to copy the data to another schema table to get the same order what should i do. My situation is i cannot add order by in select statement. It is better if i can do like this 
`INSERT INTO SHE.TRANSFERS ( SELECT * FROM HE.TRANSFERS ORDER BY TSID )`;

Comment: @JimGarrison as you said the order could be different for different executions, i tried that select multiple times. But i get same order when i execute in one schema. Note that i didn't use order by clause

Comment: I repeat: THE DATABASE IS NOT REQUIRED TO RETURN ROWS IN ANY ORDER UNLESS YOU SPECIFY 'ORDER BY'.  This is the way the operation of SQL is defined.  Rows "in the database" have no order.  You specify what you want at the time of the query.  Omitting ORDER BY tells the database you don't care.  The fact that you get _what looks to you like a specific order_ is a coincidence due to the underlying implementation.   You cannot rely on this under any circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ORDER BY` and select the column the will represent the order. a Query resuld will not be ordered in any specific way if you didnt requested it. this is how SQL works...

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without modifying the select query.

Comment: @smartkid You can make a view that does the ORDER BY - and select from the view

Answer (score 1):

There is a relation between the `ROWID` and the ordering of a row in Oracle.

As stated in this [Oracle Documentation Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm), a Row Id is unique on the level of the table. However, as mentioned by my friend in the comments below, its not guaranteed that the ordering of a row is the same as the RowId order if you didn't specify the `Order by clause`. One reason I know for this is that:

If you are using an **Index**, *RowID* in the indexed table will be different, so ordering on ROWID in this case [might] give you a different order for the data "not indexed select, or if using a different index set".

**Test for RowID order:**

If you tried this statement: `SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM YOUR_TABLE A`, it will give you the first ROWID inserted in your table.

That explains why your inserted data order might be different from the table you selected this data from.

See below image:

[image]

Comment: By default, there is no defined order.  The data may be returned in the  order in which it happens to physically exist in the database (which is why I assume you intend to refer to the `ROWID` which is the physical address of the row).  But there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: @JustinCave, ROWID is somehow related to the order of the row in a table, but as you said, not quit necessary, pleas see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)

Comment: The ROWID does not impose (or imply) any ordering. It is merely the physical address of the row. Even _when_ the query is using an index that does not imply any ordering. Asynch I/O, multi-block reads, synchronized scans between different sessions and many more other factors will change the order in which the rows are retrieved. `SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM YOUR_TABLE A` will **not** give you the "*first ROWID inserted*". It will give you the row with the lowest *physical address*. That could well be the "last row" inserted. Or the 42nd row that was inserted. Or the 365373 row that was updated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I agree, that's why I stated that **Index** is one of the reasons I'm aware of regarding the order in a select statement, in short, if you don't specify an `Order By` clause, it will be up to the database engine to decide how the data will be ordered, which is something you can't depend on if you need to maintain an order to your selected data

Comment: Again: the usage of an index does **not** have any influence on the order of the rows returned

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It's an observation, and also I stated that it is not a guaranteed reason, but from my observation, it happens that they have common order, data and ROWID, even if there is no relation documented, it is happening, at least in the most basic scenarios.  what matters for the sake of the question: if the order is an issue for the developer, he must use an `Order By` clause.   If you have any documentation about this please supply me with the link, couldn't find reliable sources

Comment: Yet another note, you are saying that `SELECT MIN(ROWID)` will not give the first inserted row, well, your statement is not true according to the [Oracle Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm). Quote from the link: **The position of the row in the data block (first row is 0)**

Comment: The first row in a block is not necessarily the first inserted row.